Matlab R2015a fdatool error " No constructor 'handle.listener' with matching signature found"
Error dialog was displayed here
My problem:
Matlab gives an error box dialog when using fdatool with FIR filter. I clicked to the View button to see visual results then an error box dialog was displayed.
Why this happened?
What should I do to fix it?
I tried to reinstall Matlab, but it still there.
Thanks for all your help!

This is not a question about programming. Contact your MATLAB representative. This is commercial software with world-class support, you paid for the software, let the maker fix it.
